# "makedeb.sh: No such file or directory" while installing Back in Time

Tags: software-installation

Clearly I'm a Linux sub-rookie...
All I'm trying to do is to install "Back in Time".
According to the developer's web site I am to type the following commands:

```
./makedeb.sh
sudo dpkg -i backintime-common-<version>.deb
sudo dpkg -i backintime-gnome-<version>.deb
sudo dpkg -i backintime-notify-<version>.deb
```

Source: in the README file, in the installer package at: http://backintime.le-web.org

Problem is when I enter just the fist line, it replies saying:

```
makedeb.sh: No such file or directory
```

I also typed `sudo` just in case, without avail :(

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using this PPA: [ppa:bit-team/stable  [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~bit-team/+archive/stable).

Run these commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backintime-gnome backintime-notify
```

The advantages over installing from a `.tar.gz` file are that:

- Automatic updates via Ubuntu's *Software Updater*.
- Installation system-wide, and including a .desktop launcher.

Comment: PPA allows for auto updates when they have fixes. Good deal!

Comment: Thanks for the advise. 
Should I uninstall the 1st attempt? Before I enter those commands?

Comment: @user196702 No, there should be no need. Just run the commands then use the version of Back In Time in the Dash. Delete the old folder that you extracted if you're confused.

Answer (score 1):

As per the instructions you have to [download a tar file](http://backintime.le-web.org/download/backintime/backintime-1.0.34.tar.gz) but they didn't go out of their way to make it clear at http://backintime.le-web.org/download_page - and once it's downloaded, you extract it and Voila! there is the *makedeb.sh* file

Comment: Excellent, thanks a bunch K7AAY.
Does it matter where I extracted to?
I initially extracted it to Home/Apps/Back in Time/

Comment: I'd do it in /home unless their directions specify otherwise, as a general rule.

Comment: I have moved the package contents to Home/, but still not working :(
Still says "No such file or directory".
I noticed a "makedeb.sh" file with the extracted files.

Comment: Errr... `/home` not `HOME/`

Comment: Actually, I was putting them in the username directory :(
Already corrected this by moving them to /home.
Now the 1st line of code worked!
Unfortunately that's as far I went :(
The next line of code got me back to the 1st error message